# Ошибка: TypeError: 'QMainWindow' object is not callable

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Открываю второе окно истории; первый раз открывается, потом закрывается, а при повторном действии выдаёт ошибку:

> TypeError: 'QMainWindow' object is not callable.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from oneicran import Ui_oneicran
from hictori import Ui_hictori


#главное окно
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
oneicran = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_oneicran()
ui.setupUi(oneicran)
oneicran.show()

def beak():
    hictori.close()
    oneicran.show()

def hictori():
    #история
    global hictori
    hictori = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_hictori()
    ui.setupUi(hictori)
    oneicran.close()
    hictori.show()
    ui.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(lambda:beak())

ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda:hictori())
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Если какой-то из ответов помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def hictori():
    ^^^^^^^ функция
    #история
    global hictori
           ^^^^^^^ переменная
    hictori = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ^^^^^^^ переменная
    ...
ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda:hictori())
                                       ^^^^^^^ функция
```

У вас выше отмеченные мной функция и переменная имеют абсолютно одинаковое название. Питон их не никак не различает со своей динамической типизацией, для него все объекты одинаковые, это всё просто переменные, тип их он узнаёт только в момент их использования (и потом тут же забывает обратно). После присваивания `hictori = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()` переменная `hictori` перестаёт указывать на функцию и начинает указывать на объект типа `QtWidgets.QMainWindow`. Поэтому следующий вызов `lambda:hictori()` уже не может вызвать вашу функцию, а пытается вызвать этот объект `QMainWindow` как функцию.

Назовите разными именами переменную и функцию для начала. Хотя думаю в вашем коде будут и другие проблемы, вы, судя по стилю кода, пока не очень понимаете, что вообще происходит и как нужно писать программы.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример. 
Вы не предоставили модули **oneicran.py** и **hictori.py** и я не смог проверить то что написал.

Глобальные переменные - это ЗЛО.

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Вот как примерно может выглядеть ваше приложение:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from oneicran import Ui_oneicran
from hictori import Ui_hictori


class HictoriWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_hictori):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HictoriWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.parent = parent
        self.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(self.go_main)  

    def go_main(self):
        self.parent.show()
        self.hide()                 
        

#главное окно
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_oneicran):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(self.go_hictori)

        self.hictori = HictoriWindow(self)
        self.hictori.hide()

    def go_hictori(self):
        self.hictori.show()
        self.hide()         


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ЕгорАвдеев что не так?